# How to set a 24 byte length key to elixir/erlang block_encrypt/4 function using des_ede3 as mode of encryption

Tags: erlang, elixir, 3des

Am trying to send data to an external api that expects encrypted data using 3DES encryption but am having issues understanding how to pass my ***api key*** as the *key* field to erlangs ***des_ede3*** cipher.

According to erlangs cipher docs ***des_ede3*** expects 3 keys that are all 8 bytes in length. How can i pass my 24 byte api key as the key to elixir/erlang :cryptoblock_encrypt/4 function

```
*** how can i pass key to block_encrypt/4 ***
key = "123456789012345678901234"
data = "hello world! The world is yours"
block_size = 8
cipher = :crypto.block_encrypt(:des_ede3, [key, key, key], iv, pad(data, block_size))
```

How do i pass my 24 byte api key as the key to erlangs block_encrypt/4 in order for me to pass data to the external api.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [binary pattern matching](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#binaries-and-bitstrings):

```rb
<<k1 :: binary-size(8),
  k2 :: binary-size(8),
  k3 :: binary-size(8)>> = "123456789012345678901234"
#⇒ "123456789012345678901234"

{k1, k2, k3}
#⇒ {"12345678", "90123456", "78901234"}
```

Comment: Let try this out and get back. Thanks alot