# des-ecb Encryption in elixir/erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir

How do i pass a 24 byte key to elixir/erlang block_encrypt des-ecb cipher.

As a follow up to my previous question [How to set a 24 byte length key to elixir/erlang block_encrypt/4 function using des_ede3 as mode of encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478114/how-to-set-a-24-byte-length-key-to-elixir-erlang-block-encrypt-4-function-using) that i was able to get working, Am trying to pass a 24byte key to the key field in elixir/erlang block_encrypt method.

Below is what i have so far.

```
# this failed
key = "Fget63htyu3nvu28nuineiru34"
<<key_1::binary-8, key_2::binary-8, key_3::binary-8>> = key
cipher = :crypto.block_encrypt(:des_ecb, {key_1, key_2, key_3}, pad(data, 8))
```

How do i pass the 24 byte length key as an 8 byte key thats required by the des_ecb cipher.

Comment: Why do you use [the deprecated function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#block_encrypt-3) in the first place?

Comment: des_ecb is not a valid parameter for crypto:block_encrypt/3 ([ref documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#block_encrypt-3))